# rsyslogd issues , logged with openlog () but logs going to /var/log/messages

Tags: c, gcc, syslog, libc, rsyslog

i have a c program the code is

```
 setlogmask (LOG_UPTO (LOG_NOTICE));
 openlog ("thelog", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);
 syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "thelog : started by User %d", getuid ());
 syslog (LOG_INFO, "thelog: an info is logging");
 closelog();
```

the code is working properly BUT the issue is the log is being logged to the file 
/var/log/messages , i have  /etc/rsyslog.conf  no and syslog.conf

I want the logs to be logged to a new file  /var/log/thelog.log file

how to fix this  issue .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want LOCAL1 to be logged to a separate file you

1. tell syslog so by properly editing its config file
2. have syslogd reload its config by sending a `kill -HUP`.

Configuration

Add a specific line for local1, like this one

```
local1.*                -/var/log/thelog.log
```

Before

```
*.*;mail.none;news.none    -/var/log/messages
```

and remove local1 from the configuration for local?.*

```
local0.*              -/var/log/localmessages
local2,local3.*       -/var/log/localmessages
```

Once the configuration file is ready

```
kill -HUP <pid-of-syslogd>
```

Comment: here local1 means ?? 
openlog ("thelog", >>>>>>  openlog ("local1",

Comment: These are actual lines from syslog's config file, `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.  Open the file, read it and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: It seems that kill -HUP is not valid anymore. `man rsyslogd`
reports that since v5, a "real restart" (e.g. /etc/rc.d/rsyslogd restart) is needed.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have a local1.* -/var/log/myfile.log BEFORE the *.*.;mail........ -/var/log/messages line, and have restarted rsyslog service to no avail. I still don't see /var/log/myfile.log file growing in size for example. Any other clues?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this like -

```
local1.*                        -/var/log/myfile.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none              -/var/log/syslog
```

restart syslogd service as
sudo service rsyslog restart